Can't proxying React Frontend with Vite to Flask Backend in a Docker Container
I can't proxy my React frontend made with Vite to the Backend my with Flask.
This is my vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        // target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        // target: 'http://task-tracker-db:5000', // Per docker
        // target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', // Per docker
        target: 'http://backend:5000', // Per docker
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
})

My api.py file is
if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True) # Per provare in locale
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True) #Per docker

And this is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=api.py
      - FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@db:3306/mydb
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge

What I tried to do:

Changed the target proxy (in the vite.config.ts) with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and with the Docker name (http://backend:5000).
Run flask serveron "0.0.0.0"
Write on the Dockerfile of backend this CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]

This is the error I get
[vite] http proxy error: /token
 AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]: 
     at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1139:18)
     at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1712:7)

